# 'Missing closing brace } assumed here' Scala worksheet error

Tags: scala

The below code causes this compile time error : `Missing closing brace } assumed here`

This object is defined within a Scala worksheet named 'Currying' . I think the code is correct ?

```
object Currying {

      def add(x:Int, y:Int) = x + y

    add(1, 2)  // 3
} //compile error is here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just noticed when I remove the comment '// 3' it works, perhaps a worksheet bug

Comment: I saw same behaviour on ScalaIDE `Build id: 3.0.3-20140327-1716-Typesafe`